# Using jq, extract fields and subfields from a list of objects, grouping paired subfields for saving to csv

Tags: csv, jq

With this data:

```
[
  {
    "c": "A",
    "e": "B",
    "score": 0.99,
    "v": [
      {
        "context": "asdf",
        "score": 0.98,
        "url": "..."
      },
      {
        "context": "bcdfd",
        "score": 0.97,
        "url": "..."
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    ...
  }
]
```

(Note the outer list)

I'm looking to extract:

```
A, B, 0.99, asdf, 0.98, bcdfd, 0.97
```

So, the best I'm able to do is

```
jq -r '.[] | [.c, .e, .score, .v[].context, .v[].score ] | @csv'
```

which yields

```
A, B, 0.99, asdf, bcdfd, 0.998, 0.97
```

I understand that the `.v[].context` and `.v[score]` are just spitting out each set of values, not intertwining them.

What magic am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You want to run a `.context,.score` filter on each element of `v` I think:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | [.c, .e, .score, (.v[] | .context,.score)] | @csv' file.json
"A","B",0.99,"asdf",0.98,"bcdfd",0.97
```

This is equivalent to using the builtin `map` function without assembling the results back into an array.

Comment: Yes, indeed. And now I have a deeper appreciation of the role of the parens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a JSON-encoded CSV record for each top-level array element, and then extracts and decodes them. For each of the top-level elements, the values of the sub-array is incorporated by "flattening" the array.

```bash
jq -r 'map([ .c,.e,.score, (.v|map([.context, .score])) ] | flatten | @csv)[]' file
```

Given a test document equivalent of the following:

```json
[
   {
      "c": "A",
      "e": "B",
      "score": 0.99,
      "v": [
         { "context": "asdf", "score": 0.98, "url": "..." },
         { "context": "bcdfd", "score": 0.97, "url": "..." }
      ]
   },
   {
      "c": "A",
      "e": "B",
      "score": 0.99,
      "v": [
         { "context": "asdf", "score": 0.98, "url": "..." },
         { "context": "asdf", "score": 0.98, "url": "..." },
         { "context": "bcdfd", "score": 0.97, "url": "..." }
      ]
   },
   {
      "c": "A",
      "e": "B",
      "score": 0.99,
      "v": [
         { "context": "asdf", "score": 0.98, "url": "..." },
         { "context": "asdf", "score": 0.98, "url": "..." },
         { "context": "asdf", "score": 0.98, "url": "..." },
         { "context": "bcdfd", "score": 0.97, "url": "..." }
      ]
   }
]
```

... we get

```
"A","B",0.99,"asdf",0.98,"bcdfd",0.97
"A","B",0.99,"asdf",0.98,"asdf",0.98,"bcdfd",0.97
"A","B",0.99,"asdf",0.98,"asdf",0.98,"asdf",0.98,"bcdfd",0.97
```

One could also reorder the operations so that a single use of the `@csv` operator gets a set of arrays (rather than repeatedly using `@csv` on single arrays):

```bash
jq -r 'map([ .c,.e,.score, (.v|map([.context, .score])) ] | flatten)[]|@csv' file
```